# Android > 4.2. How to make device boot when power is plugged in?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-ndk, autostart

There are a lot of similar questions, but problem still not solved. 
The target device is not Samsung, not HTC and does't have files called "playlpm" or "lpm". There is the "/system/bin/ipod" file but after any modifications it not executing.
If I change file content to some bash script on android v4.2 everythink works fine, but something changed in latest versions and this don't work for android 4.4.
What the difference? And how to make android v4.4 boot on power plug?

Comment: What type of device are you using, LG?

Comment: Nope, Prestigio and another chinese noname MTK based devices.

Comment: I'm running a Samsung S4 Active running CyanogenMod 12.1 and am having the same problem as above only no /system/bin/ipod file.

Comment: any progress in this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  the fact that after your editing the file it isnt running even if its valid script, i am thinking its probably your file editor. editors like notepad plus plus tend to add a lot of junk you dontsee like  /r or /n.   so what i did to make mine work open the file in notepad plus plus , do my changes, then click edit->EOL conversion-> unix.  then it worked

Comment: No. This is not editor issue. I used Vim from busybox(in android v4.4 busybox is available by default) direclty from device(adb shell). Also I tried to change this file via basic "echo some > file" principles. And I have no windows, or mac to broke this files somehow. This I think is a PolicyKit issue, but still have no idea how to fix it.